# PHP, OOP - Form Validation

Tags: php, oop, form-processing

I have created a form element class. The class is able to

1. Create HTML form elements and
2. Confirm if form has been submitted and if so, load the submitted value, for the specified form element into the object which is worked on on the page.

I have tried to make this as general as possible in order to make it reusable but since I am kind of newbie with regards to OOP it would be super cool if someone could check this and let me know if this is good OOP also if this is a good solution for what I am trying to achieve.

Here is the essential part of the class_FormControl()

```
class FormControl{
    var $finalcontrol;
    var $class = "form-control";
    var $form_error;

    protected function StartFormatting($name, $label){
        if (isset($_POST[$name]) AND $_POST[$name] != "") {
            return false;
        }
        $this->finalcontrol = "<label for='$name' >$label</label>";
        return true;
    }

    public function get_control(){
        return $this->finalcontrol;
}
}

class TextBox extends FormControl{

    public function CreateControl($obj, $name, $label, $placeholder, $value = ""){
        if($this->StartFormatting($name, $label)){
            $this->finalcontrol .= "<input type='text' class='$this->class' id='$name' name='$name' placeholder='$placeholder'";

            if ($value != "") { 
                $this->finalcontrol .= " value='$value' "; 
            }

            $this->finalcontrol .= ">";
            return true;
        } 

        $func = "set_" . $name;
        $obj->$func($_POST[$name]);
        return false;

    }
}
```

And here is how I use the class in the form page:

```
$r1 = New Recipe();
$tbx = new TextBox();
$ctrl1 = $tbx->CreateControl($r1, "Name", "Nombre", "Nombre", $r1->get_Name());
```

Now if $ctrl1 is true I go on and save the object in the database.

If $ctrl1 is false I go on and

```
echo $tbx->get_control();
```

on the right place in the page.

/Thanks!

Comment: That is a lot of code to display a textfield...

Comment: @PeeHaa - Yeah of course, to display one textfield this is overkill. But I thought having hundreds of fields on all the subpages, also including saving values to the object inside the class Ithough it would pay off in the long run... I guess your commen is answer No to question 2 then. Noted.

Comment: I see no advantage using a function than standard HTML. If you need a thousand of textfields, you can use a loop.

Comment: And, don't want to sound discouraging, but your OOP does not rely on any object principle, despite the fact you have base and child class, all this thing is pretty much functional programming. And as well, in PHP5 the properties has access levels too, also according to the convention around PHP community, methods should be `camelCase`.

Comment: Not discouraging at all :) I am very grateful for your feedback, and spending just a few minutes reading I see what you mean. I will go back studying more before I continue with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

> **Note:** This is **not** the only way to do it; it is one of many and it is my personal interpretation of the problem in 10 minutes on my lunch break. Please bear in mind that this would be *my* implementation with the little information I'd have been given. In the real world, I would find out more about the domain, but I would still adhere to the single responsibility principle in my objects and keep everything loosely coupled. These are the *main things* to take away from this post.

### OOP

First and foremost, you need to be thinking in terms of objects. Each object has it's **own single responsibility** [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle):

> In object-oriented programming, the single responsibility principle states that every context (**class**, function, variable, etc.) should have a **single responsibility**, and that responsibility should be **entirely encapsulated by the context**. All its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility. *[emphasis my own]*.

What you are doing is *placing procedural code into class methods*. This does not make it object oriented! You need to shift your mindset!

### Objects

You're building a form builder. A form is comprised of elements. Instantly, I am thinking of:

- A `Form` object
- A `FormElement` object

The above objects are specific representations of an Entity or ValueObject. [Domain Driven Design](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/EvansClassification.html).

`FormElement` could be an Interface that all form elements (like input boxes, buttons etc) must conform to.

```php
class Form
{
   /**
    * @var FormElement[]
    */
    protected $elements;

   /**
    * Add a FormElement to the form
    *
    * @param FormElement $element
    */
    public function addFormElement(FormElement $element)
    {
        $this->elements[] = $element;
    }
}

interface FormElement
{
   /**
    * @return The generated html for the given form element
    */
    public function getHtml();
}
```

Now all you need to do is make sure that each of your objects that implement `FormElement` return exactly what you want within the `FormElement::getHtml()` method and it'll all still work great when you add new elements to the `Form`, because it will be the `Form` that is calling `getHtml()` in a loop on each of the `FormElement` objects before adding this to it's own HTML and outputting it.

Here's an example of a `TextBoxFormElement` I would use:

```php
class TextBoxFormElement implements FormElement
{ 
   /**
    * @constructor
    *
    * This is where I am declaring that, for this to be a VALID object, it MUST have
    * the following properties passed in
    *
    * @param string $name
    * @param string $label
    * @param string $placeholder
    * @param string $value
    */
    public function __construct($id, $class, $name, $label, $placeholder, $value)
    {
        $this->id          = $id;
        $this->class       = $class;
        $this->name        = $name;
        $this->label       = $label;
        $this->placeholder = $placeholder;
        $this->value       = $value;
    }

   /**
    * Generate the html of this element
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getHtml()
    {
        return sprintf(
            "<input type='text' id='%s' class='%s' name='%s' label='%s' placeholder='%s' value='%s'>",
            $this->id, $this->class, $this->name, $this->label, $this->placeholder, $this->value
        );
    }
}
```

### SuperGlobals

You are using `$_POST` and `$_GET` in these classes. **You should not be doing this**. You should be doing the following:

> Each object your write, the public methods of these objects dictate their API. You are writing an API to those object's usages. [My own quote]

Effectively, having any sort of `$_POST` or `$_GET` couples these objects to the state of these superglobals. How are you going to test them? You're  going to have to mock out (or fake) the contents of these superglobals each time you want to test them.

No. What you *should* be doing is forgetting about your own application for a moment and coding these objects so you can use them *in any application*. Then, you **pass in** the values into the objects constructor or methods. Do not use `$_POST` or `$_GET` directly within this class.

### Conclusion

You are not writing OO code. But I'm not going to write it for you. I will, however, write the methods that I would expect to call when using your library in the hope that you can figure out for yourself your own implementation. Keep everything separate, use a **single responsibility** for every object (this is **not** overkill, it is object oriented programming), and keep learning:

```php
// Sanitize and validate input data obviously you would have a RequestValidator used before you even get to this point, making sure exactly what you want can be used by the library
$name = $_POST['name'];

/** Create our form **/
$form = new Form;

/** TextBoxFormElement implements FormElement **/
$textBox1 = new TextBoxFormElement($name, 'Label', 'Placeholder' /** etc **/);

/** Add our FormElement **/
$form->addFormElement($textBox1);

/** Generate our html - the form generates it's own HTML as well as calling getHTML() on the FormElement objects in a loop **/
echo $form->getHtml();
```

**That is IT**. That is the object API you should be creating. It should be as simple as that. Now go forth with this magical knowledge and learn.

---

Extra info: An alternative is to take a look at the [Visitor Pattern](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.IuseVisitor). Basically, you separate the thing that generates the output from the thing that holds the data. Here's [more info](http://manski.net/2013/05/the-visitor-pattern-explained/) on the topic if you want to take a look at that.

Always remember that your code should be readable and easy to understand, and that if it helps - you should create some industry standard UML diagrams to go alongside your code.

Comment: nice explanation searching for exact content :)

Comment: This is the best example, I have come across, for using interfaces.